# is it sensible to use monte carlo to predict sum of time-series over an interval?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have created a model that forecasts out a time series at the daily level along with prediction intervals two months into the future.  There is little to no auto-correlation in the time series so I used a regression-based model.  The model's out-of-sample accuracy is generally excellent.

I am now examining what the sum of activity (e.g., how many $$ will be spent) will be over a period (e.g., 11-1-2015 to 12-1-2015).  To find the sum activity, I can just add up the prediction's for each day.

I would like to place a confidence interval around my sum estimate (`e.g., predicted sum = $10,000 and there is a 95% chance we will spend between $7,000 and $13,000`).  So one question, if I assume that the uncertainty around my daily estimate is normally distributed, is it sensible to run monte-carlo simulations in which I:

1. get a number for each day from the N(that days mean, σ2 derived from that days prediction interval)
2. sum those numbers for the whole time period to get a predicted sum for that time period
3. repeat a million times
4. calculate distribution of predicted sums

If this approach is not sensible or if there is a more standard alternative, can you let me know?

Comment: Your normal distribution assumption, along with mild additional assumptions (such as constant variance of residuals) places you squarely in the classical least-squares regression theory, which gives relatively simple formulas for such prediction intervals.

Comment: Rob Hyndman has a post on his blog that may be useful here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-intervals-for-aggregates/